# Code is automatically rounding value

Tags: swift

I am trying to use a small decimal value as a double but the Mac app I am writing is automatically rounding the value up or down. Here is my code after a button is tapped to confirm the value change:

```
self.desiredReturns = self.desiredReturnTextField.doubleValue
print ("val is \(self.desiredReturnTextField.doubleValue) ** \(self.desiredReturns)")
```

It prints `val is 0.0 ** 0.0` when I input `0.0001` but when I input 0.001 it prints normally as `val is 0.001 ** 0.001`.

Am I doing something wrong here? Why does this happen with small numbers?

Here is how I display it as a percentage in my UI and it also prints as 0

```
func formatPercent(value: Double) -> String {
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.percent
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
    let result = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value))
    return result!
}

self.formatPercent(value: self.desiredReturns)
```

Comment: If you stop in the debugger and inspect the variables, what do you see?  (I'm wondering whether there is truly a problem with the data or only with `print`.)

Comment: Your value is fine. It's just that `print` defaults to showing 3 decimal places when showing `Double` values.

Comment: ok perfect but even when I try to display it in my UI, it only shows up as 0. I just added to my question to show how I am displaying it in my UI. is there anyway to change this to display more accurate numbers?

Comment: I tried your code in a playground and don't see a problem. `print(formatPercent(value: 0.000001))` resulted in a display of "0.0001%".

Comment: this is exactly the code I am using `let percentageVal = self.formatPercent(value: self.desiredReturnsSellPrimary)
            self.desiredReturnInUseSellPrimaryLabel.stringValue = "current: \(percentageVal)"`

Comment: and it is displaying `0%`

Comment: it is a Mac OS X app not an iOS app if that changes anything

Comment: I happened to do it in a Mac playground, but I wouldn't expect that to matter.    (Try it with a literal number rather than a variable as a sanity check?)

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work

Comment: I don't think it matters but I am doing an update to the value using the didSet on a variable. So I am assigning a value to a variable and then the {didSet{//code here }} code is executing

Comment: is it a good thing to use `.doubleValue` instead of `.stringValue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this was happening was that there was a number formatter associated to my text field. the number formatter style was set to decimal and that rounds values to 3 decimal places.